# To find and replace escaped quotes in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, string

My database has content that has been previously escaped, resulting in string such as

> This value is \"invalid\".

I want to get rid of escape character `\` but I'm having a hard time to find these rows. My first attempt

```
select value from content where value like '%\\"%';
```

fails to separate `\"` from `"`, and returns valid rows such as

> This value is "valid".

So how can I query for the string `\"`, preferably in a way than can be used in an update clause to remove the slash?

EDIT: SQL Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc3d3/6
Notice that the query at line 3 returns both rows.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to? The slash is never displayed, so while it may be inconsistent in the table, it won't be a pain to the user.

Comment: The problem it's that it is being displayed, and I really don't want to dig into the application code.

Comment: Strange. I can't debug this using SQL Fiddle, because the strings are displayed the same, and even have the same length: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db79b/2 Something I'm not aware of is happening in the background.

Comment: I believe you need to escape slash to insert it, like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc3d3/1

Comment: Are you trying to insert a slash, or remove rows that have it in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to replace `\"` for `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked your sqlfiddle.

This gets the invalid rows:

```
SELECT * from myTable where content<>REPLACE(content,'\\\"','\"')
```

If this works, then you can simply update your `content` column to `REPLACE(content,'\\\"','\"')`.